Safely remote connect to Ubuntu desktop from Windows
I have only used Ubuntu as a casual user so please bear with me :)
Id like to remotely connect to an Ubuntu Desktop from a Windows Laptop. I have followed a couple of tutorials but am not sure about how safe this would be.
I have configured it following these tutorials:

Remote Desktop to Ubuntu from Windows
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-remote-desktop-from-windows
https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-22-04-remote-desktop-access-from-windows-10

They all seem to cover the same points about installing xrdp and so on. It seems to be working fine when I tested both devices on the same network. However Im a bit apprehensive about connecting through the Internet (for example connecting to the Ubuntu Desktop in my usual residence from my laptop in a hotel).
In this reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/j6ppzh/how_secure_is_windows_remote_desktop_should_i_be/
They say that connecting it through the internet is a big nono and I should use a VPN. In my last office job we used GlobalProtect but it was for Windows-Windows connections only and was all handled by the IT department.
Are there any VPN alternatives (preferably free)? Also which device should have a VPN? The one trying to connect (Laptop) or the one hosting the connection (Desktop)?
So in short: I'd like to know how to ensure that the remote connection is safe if its established through the internet.
Thanks!
